# Are there any maintened [sic] gems for downloading videos from youtube?

Tags: ruby, youtube

I need to download youtube videos and convert them to mp3. Are there any maintened [sic] gems for downloading videos from youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Not a gem, but an executable you can run in your shell - `youtube-dl`. It's a python program actually. But you can call it from ruby the same way you run any other shell command (back ticks).